# \r при записи в файл работает неправильно

Tags: python

При записи в файл Python определяет **\r** как **\n** и делает перенос строки. Как это исправить?
Вот мой тестовый код:

```py
f = open("test.txt", "w")
f.write("Это \\r\rЭто \\n\nА это \\r\\n\r\nКак вам?")
f.close()
```

При попытке посмотреть файл, который он создал, перед глазами открывается такая картина:

```py
Это \r
Это \n
А это \r\n

Как вам?
```

Исходя из моих знаний в области работы **\r** картина должна выглядеть так:

```
Это \n
А это \r\n
Как вам?
```

В данном же случае, **\r** просто заменяется на перенос строки, что искажает нужный мне текст.
**Вопрос:** как заставить Python записывать текст в файл правильно?

Comment: Что вы хотите записать два символа подряд \ + r или `\r` ? ;)

Comment: Спецсимвол `\r` переносит курсор терминала в начало текущей строки. В текстовом файле нет никакого курсора и нет никакого терминала, поэтому желаемый результат в текстовом файле вы не получите.

Comment: @andreymal Но только если как виндовый `\r\n` AFAIK.

Comment: Из идей пока это переводить курсор по байтам через f.seek(n) но в работе немного изврат. Или подготавливать данные построчно в коде а потом записывать.

Comment: Отображение значения и само значение - две большие разницы. Первое определяется средством (программой)  отображения - и если ей хочется `\r` отображать как переход на новую  строку, то ничего с этим не сделать.

Comment: Какая у вас операционка? Выведите содержимое файла на терминал командой `cat` или `type` - и вы увидите именно то, что хотели увидеть. А если смотреть "сырое" содержимое файла каким-то редактором, то вы увидите в нём, конечно же, все команды, которые вы отдавали, последовательно.